# Ember if helper are resolved only the first time

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using Ember js, latest 1.7.0, I want something to be displayed based on a condition, but the condition of course changes a lot.

But Ember seems to only resolve my code once, meaning once it becomes true, it stays true no matter what, so the at first its not displayed, but then it is displayed but empty.

here is my code snippet

```
{{#if controller.selectedTmHit}}
    {{tm-results-footer selectedTmHit=controller.selectedTmHit}}
{{/if}}
```

how can I update an if condition in ember ?

** EDIT

this is my controller

```
TsWebEditor.SubfileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs:['application'],
    jobId:Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.currentTask.jobId"),
    selectedTmHit:null
});
```

and this is my partial main partial

```
<div id="tabTmSearch" class="tab tab-pane active">
      {{partial "subfile/tm-tab"}}
</div>
```

and this is my subfile/tm-tab partial

```
<div class="container-fluid">
{{#if controller.selectedSegment}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tm-main-source">
            {{tm-hit-source locale=sourceLocale segment=controller.selectedSegment}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row tm-results-table">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
            <tbody>
            {{#each tmHit in controller.selectedSegment.tmHits}}
                {{tm-hit tmHit=tmHit}}
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{{/if}}
</div>
{{#if controller.selectedTmHit}}
    {{tm-results-footer selectedTmHit=controller.selectedTmHit}}
{{/if}}
```

at first it is displayed correctly but once the if condition is true it is not rerendered, although the value of the selectedTmHit is changed and it only displayed an empty div

Comment: can you show the code for `selectedTmHit` ?

Comment: And the entire context of the template (which template it is).

Comment: What updates selectedTmHit, and what is the model with this controller?

Comment: What @Kingpin2k asked for is needed. If we don't know what is updating `selectedTmHit` we can't really help.

Comment: thanks a lot but I found my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, I had an exception that wasn't caught and did not appear to me, and EmberJS does its rendering after all the other stuff has finished, so when my code threw an exception it did not complete the rendering process because that event was terminated and couldn't return back to the run loop for the execution to continue.

So if you are having the same thing, check your exceptions and make sure you get back to the loop and that it finishes processing.